# Can I set my mongodb read preference to secondary in a reliable way?

Tags: mongodb

I am running a 5 node replica set as 1 primary 3 secondary and 1 arbiter node. When I check my replication status with db.printSlaveReplicationInfo() I see 1 or 2 seconds of replication lag and I think this is perfect.

My question here is, can I set my read preference as secondary and have at most a specific amount of latency guaranteed. I mean, if mongo replication slows down for a reason and replication lag increases to a certain value, can mongodb redirect my reads to primary node automatically?

Answer (score 0):

As I just figured it out an option introduced in 3.4 version, this setting is for the task just I was looking for. maxStalenessSeconds lets us specify a staleness period on secondary reads.